# Implement library callback

Tags: go

I am trying to implement a client library in Go. The client app would import this library and use its methods. One such method is to set a notification on a certain event and if that event happens then the client app should receive a callback. I am stuck with the question of how to call the client app function from my library. Below are the go playground links for what I am trying to do. Let's say there is a package main which is the client app, this app uses client lib which is in package test.

**package main:**

```
package main
  
import (
    "fmt"
    "test"
)

func main() {
    obj := test.New_data()
    fmt.Println("This is main")
    fmt.Println("Name is ", obj.Name)
}

func (dObj *(test.Write_data)) Callback() {
    fmt.Println("This is callback function")    
}
```

**package test:**

```
package test
  
import (
    "fmt"
)

type Write_data struct {
    Name string
}

func New_data() *Write_data {
    var obj Write_data
    obj.Name = "Sample string"
    fmt.Println("Name is", obj.Name)
    obj.Callback()
    return &obj
}
```

Now the app will define a callback function that needs to be called by the library. Is there a way this can be done? The way I have done does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this:

Use a callback function:

```
func LibraryFunction(callback func(Event)) {
  ...
   callback(event)
}
```

Or, register a callback function to some sort of registry:

```
var callbacks []func(Event)

func AddNotificationCallback(f func(Event)) {
   callbacks=append(callbacks,f)
}

func Notify(ev Event) {
   for _,x:=range callbacks {
      x(ev)
   }
}
```

Instead of callback functions, you can do the same thing with interfaces:

```
type Receiver interface {
    EventHappened(Event)
}
```

You can pass any struct implementing this interface to library functions, or register to a notification receiver list.

If the library is producing these events asynchronously, then you can use channels to send events back, but from your description it doesn't look like this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In Go, having a receiver with a type from a different package is not legal; the code you have provided will not compile.

---

Instead, consider passing the callback function from the client application to the library.
This is a common pattern. One example of its usage is the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Go library](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub?tab=doc#Subscription.Receive). The signature looks as follows:

```
func (s *Subscription) Receive(ctx context.Context, f func(context.Context, *Message)) error
```

In this case the `Receive()` function calls the provided callback function `f` whenever a new message is received on the `*Subscription`, and thus the "client app" code would look like this:

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, "project-id")
if err != nil {
    // TODO: Handle error.
}
sub := client.Subscription("subName")

callback := func(ctx context.Context, m *pubsub.Message) {
    // TODO: Handle message.
    m.Ack()
}
err = sub.Receive(ctx, callback)
if err != context.Canceled {
    // TODO: Handle error.
}
```

This is a slightly modified version of the example code in the same docs referenced above.

An even more simplified version can be found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/rQP_yrcqZA9).